# Symfony set up Export class and Configuration for your bundle

Tags: symfony

I'm facing an unexpected behavior while building a bundle in a symfony project.
I've built an exportclass in the DependencyInjection namespace where I just do:

```
public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $configuration = new Configuration();
        $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);

        $container->setParameter( 'auction.path', $config[ 'path' ] );
        $container->setParameter( 'auction.miao', $config[ 'miao' ] );
        $container->setParameter( 'auction.stock.pain', $config[ 'stock' ][ 'pain' ] );

        $loader = new YamlFileLoader(
            $container,
            new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config/')
        );
    }
}
```

In theory I should simply define 3 variables. If I dump the config variable I get the following output:

```
Array
(
    [path] => C:\progetti_symfony\repository-cms\src\AuctionBundle\DependencyInjection../web/images/tmp/
    [miao] => C:\progetti_symfony\repository-cms\src\AuctionBundle\DependencyInjection../web/images/pmt/
)
```

where the nested stock.pain part (see next snippetfor details) is ignored.

I then have a Configuration class in the same folder Where I define the config for this bundle (and here is where I lose my compass):

```
class Configuration implements ConfigurationInterface
{
    public function getConfigTreeBuilder()
    {
        $treeBuilder = new TreeBuilder();
                $rootNode = $treeBuilder->root('auction');

        $rootNode
                        ->children()
                            ->scalarNode('path')->defaultValue(__DIR__ . '../web/images/tmp/')->end()
                            ->scalarNode('miao')->defaultValue(__DIR__ . '../web/images/pmt/')->end()
                            ->arrayNode('stock')
                                ->children()
                                    ->scalarNode('pain')->defaultValue(__DIR__ . '../web/images/mpt/')->end()
                                ->end()
                            ->end()
                        ->end();
        return $treeBuilder;
    }
}
```

Any suggestion on how to structure and access this configuration?

Comment: what is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

You can define `stock` as empty array if it is not set. Then `pain` will be set to default value.

```
$rootNode
    ->beforeNormalization()
        ->ifTrue(function($v) {
            return !isset($v['stock']);
        })
        ->then(function($v) {
            $v['stock'] = array();
            return $v;
        })
        ->end()
    ->children()
        ->scalarNode('path')->defaultValue(__DIR__ . '../web/images/tmp/')->end()
        ->scalarNode('miao')->defaultValue(__DIR__ . '../web/images/pmt/')->end()
        ->arrayNode('stock')
            ->children()
                ->scalarNode('pain')->defaultValue(__DIR__ . '../web/images/mpt/')->end()
                ->end()
            ->end()
        ->end();
```

**UPDATE:**

Better decision: use `addDefaultsIfNotSet()`

```
$rootNode
    ->children()
        ->scalarNode('path')->defaultValue(__DIR__ . '../web/images/tmp/')->end()
        ->scalarNode('miao')->defaultValue(__DIR__ . '../web/images/pmt/')->end()
        ->arrayNode('stock')
            ->addDefaultsIfNotSet()
            ->children()
                ->scalarNode('pain')->defaultValue(__DIR__ . '../web/images/mpt/')->end()
                ->end()
            ->end()
        ->end();
```